# Replace String with Dictionary c#

Tags: c#, string, replace

I need to replace all placeholders like `{text}` with a corresponding value from a dictionary.

This is my code:

```
var args = new Dictionary<string, string> {
   {"text1", "name"},
   {"text2", "Franco"}
};
saveText(Regex.Replace("Hi, my {text1} is {text2}.", @"\{(\w+)\}", m => args[m.Groups[1].Value]));
```

The problem is: if the text in the input string does not exist in the dictionary, it throws an exception but I rather need to replace the placeholder with the string `"null"`.

Comment: Do you expect that the key value could contain valid Regex codes? If it does then this kind of Regex replacement won't work.

Comment: @Enigmativity why wouldn't it?

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski - Try replacing the `{text1}` with `{text.1}` in both the key and the input string. The result of the OP's code becomes `Hi, my {text.1} is Franco.`.

Comment: @Enigmativity Yes, it's because of the regex used. If you want to enable this scenario, replace `@"\{(\w+)\}"` with `@"\{(.+?)\}"` and it will work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just expand your lambda:

```
var args = new Dictionary<string, string> {
   {"text1", "name"},
   {"text2", "Franco"}
};

saveText(Regex.Replace("Hi, my {text1} is {text2}.", @"\{(\w+)\}", m => {
    string value;
    return args.TryGetValue(m.Groups[1].Value, out value) ? value : "null";
}));
```

Comment: Thanks, that is i needed, simple and functional :D

Answer (score 0):

I would use LINQ to create a single `Func<string, string>` that performs all of the replacements in one go.

Here's how:

```
var replace = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "text1", "name" },
    { "text2", "Franco" }
}
    .Select(kvp => (Func<string, string>)
        (x => x.Replace(String.Format("{{{0}}}", kvp.Key), kvp.Value)))
    .Aggregate<Func<string, string>, Func<string, string>>(
        x => Regex.Replace(x, @"\{(\w+)\}", "null"),
        (a, f) => x => a(f(x)));

var result = replace( "Hi, my {text1} is {text2} and {text3} and {text4}.");

// result == "Hi, my name is Franco and null and null."
```

Comment: This performs one replacement per key/value pair, so it's certainly not "in one go". Also, it doesn't replace unrecognized keys with `"null"`. Oh, and it leaves the braces too. Expected result: `"Hi, my {text1} is {text2} and {text3}." -> "Hi, my name is Franco and null."`

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski - Sorry, I missed a few key points in the question. I've updated my answer and I believe it functions correctly.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski - As an additional note - my solution will handle cases when the key values contain Regex special characters.

Comment: Yes, that's better :) but try your solution with `new Dictionary<string, string> { { "text1", "Foo {text2}" }, { "text2", "Bar {text1}" } }`. The outcome won't be `"Hi, my Foo {text2} is Bar {text1} and null and null."` as expected. I think you're overcomplicating things here tbh ;)

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski - Irony re over-complicating it. LOL

Answer (score 0):

It seems the OP is trying to solve the problem of rendering a template. While it is fun to use regex, the problem of rendering templates is well addressed by template engines.

A good template language is [Mustache](https://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html) and a good template Engine is [stubble](https://github.com/StubbleOrg/Stubble). Even if you do not harness all the power of template engine, the overall code is still concise:

```
using Stubble.Core.Builders;
...
var args = new Dictionary<string, string> {
   {"text1", "name"},
   {"text2", "Franco"}
};
var stubble = new StubbleBuilder().Build();
saveText(stubble.Render("Hi, my {{text1}} is {{text2}} and {{text3}} and {{text4}}")
```

The default behavior of stubble is to render unknown placeholders as empty. You can however add a default, e.g. a string with value "null":

```
var stubble = new StubbleBuilder().Configure(settings =>
{
  settings.AddValueGetter(typeof(object), (key, value, ignoreCase) => "null");
}).Build();
Dictionary<string, object> args = new Dictionary<string, object> {
  {"text1", "name"},
  {"text2", "Franco"}
};
saveText(stubble.Render("Hi, my {{text1}} is {{text2}} and {{text3}} and {{text4}}")
```